# How Hibernate query latest data but not from cache

Tags: hibernate

I create a login function which will user Hibernate query to retrieve the data from mysql. However, this login function always retrieve the data from cache but not direct from DB even after I had modified the data via another application to the same DB.

Below is my code:

```
public User login(User entity) throws Exception {
    Transaction trns = null;
    Session session = null;
    User data = null;
    try {
        session = SessionUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        trns = session.beginTransaction();
        DaoInterface dao = new UserDaoImpl();
        data = dao.findByUniqueKey(session, entity);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (trns != null) {
            trns.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
    return data;
}
```

---

```
public User findByUniqueKey(Session session, User entity)
        throws HibernateException {
    User data = null;
    try {
        Query query = session
                .createQuery("FROM User where loginUserId = :loginUserId ");
        query.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH);
        query.setString("loginUserId", entity.getLoginUserId());
        data = (User) query.uniqueResult();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {            
        throw e;
    }
    return data;
}
```

I tried to add session.clear() before session.close() and session.evict in findByUniqueKey function, but still failed to retrieve latest data.

I am seeking the advice how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using Session.Abandon(). Abandon removes all the objects stored in a Session.

Comment: Hi, I can't get Session.Abandon() function from the hibernate Session or session API.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my problem by added trns.commit() after data = dao.findByUniqueKey(session, entity); in login method. After the code added, the method will always retrieve the latest data for next call.
I don't understand why the query is required commit function.
Anybody can advise?